How do Payment Gateways POST to my return URL in a way that the output shows up in my Browser and not their code that is POSTing
A common method that Payment Gateways work is this:

I post the amount and other secure details to the Gateway URL
The Gateway then claims to POST to my return/callback URL with the transaction outcome

In this scenario, I have a question: How does the Gateway POST to my URL but display the result of the POST in my browser rather than their POST'ing code? Are they doing the POST with a Redirect to my URL (which I think is not possible according to the HTTP spec)?
The only other way I can think of is that they send the payload with a GET that includes Javascript that POSTs locally once it reaches my server. This too is unlikely since it works even when I disable Javascript
Would really appreciate an explanation of how they do it

A brief reason for the downvote would have helped.

Turns out, I might have likely figured this out: It is likely that the Payment Gateway is responding with a Redirect 307 with a Body to my callback URL? A 307 preserves the method POST

The industry norm for sharing the response on the callback URL is to use a POST call, where the relevant details are sent as part of the form-data. This can be directly consumed in the code to render the payment information to the end user.
